# How to get Ad Break Data in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, api, graph

I am trying to get Ad Break Data from the Graph API but the documentation is lacking (read: not existent) in this regard. Does anyone know perhabs how I have to formulate the query for the Graph API to get the Ad Breaks Earnings for each Video?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

The value is available via video_insights.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/video_insights/

Towards the end of the response is: `total_video_ad_break_revenue`

There's also fields for `total_video_ad_break_ad_impressions` and  `total_video_ad_break_ad_cpm` but those are sometimes empty while the lifetime revenue is still provided.

```
{
  "name": "total_video_ad_break_revenue",
  "period": "lifetime",
  "values": [
    {
      "value": *AD_REVENUE_VALUE_HERE*
    }
  ],
  "title": "Lifetime Video Ad Break Revenue",
  "description": "An estimate of the amount you earned from ad breaks in your video, based on the number of impressions and CPM of ads shown. Actual payments may differ if there are content ownership claims or other adjustments.",
  "id": "*VIDEO_ID_HERE*/video_insights/total_video_ad_break_revenue/lifetime"
},
```